# Using a function in differents C files

Tags: c, gcc

I have the prototype of a function i `header.h` defined as :

```
void getSettings();
```

I'm using the function in a 1st source file `file1.c` say like :

```
void getSetting(){
    printf(" in file 1 \n");
}
```

this works.
I have a second source file that has to use this function, but with a different implementation  `file2.c` like :

```
void getSetting() {
    printf(" In file 2 \n");
}
```

the program crashes when I start the 2nd file, delivering
`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
error message.
and it doesn't get into the implementation of the second file. any idea if that what I'm trying is possible in `C`, if yes how ?

**UPDATE** 
to compile the code I use :

```
gcc file2.c -o o2
```

and for the first file

```
gcc file1.c -o o1
```

Comment: How are you compiling? Is this the whole code?

Comment: Are you making two different executable programs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this but you must declare the function static in the header and in both files.

Also, please do not leave empty arguments in functions, instead use void, otherwise you are indicating the function may be variadic.

So basically you want:

```
static void getSettings(void);
```

and

```
static void getSettings(void)
{
    printf(" in file 1 \n");
}
```

and

```
static void getSettings(void)
{
    printf(" In file 2 \n");
}
```

Also note, as @invalid pointed out, you may *not* want to include the prototype in the header file as a function which is of only file scope does not need to be prototyped in a header and may not need to be prototyped at all if it is defined before it is used.

Comment: You wouldn't want the declaration in a header file, since static functions are meant to be local to a file, putting it in a header file to be included makes little sense.

Comment: @Invalid Unless every file is guaranteed to have a static implementation of the function which seems to be the case here, it can then be used to specify a kind of compiler checked interface which files must implement.

Comment: Until you add another file which doesn't implement it. It makes very little sense to me to do this, you don't really gain anything from it.